# Not able to save data from admin site in django app

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

I am building an app in django to keep track of social events. I am trying to handle recurring events through django-simple-events package. Issue is when I try to save any data from the admin site, it says record successfully added but when I check my model I don't see any record. When I click the object from recent activity I get an error 404 with the following message study object with primary key u'None' does not exist.

## models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.contenttypes import generic
from events.models import Event

class Study(models.Model):
    study_event_name = models.CharField(max_length=140)
    events = generic.GenericRelation(Event)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=140)

    def save(self):
        super(Study, self).save

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.study_event_name
```

## admin.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from study.models import Study
from events.admin import EventInline

# Register your models here.

class StudyAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = EventInline,

admin.site.register(Study, StudyAdmin)
```

Can anyone help me in figuring out what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: What exactly is your custom save()-method doing? And are you aware that you are missing brackets inside of it?

Comment: I am planning to use slug to build custom urls. That's why planning to override the save method

Comment: save is working fine now. I am able to add Study objects in the db